# PHP: Can CURL follow meta redirects

Tags: php, redirect, curl, meta-tags

CURL can follow header redirects with the use of CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION but is it possible to follow meta refresh redirects?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, but you'll have to do it yourself by parsing the response and looking for things that look like:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://example.com/" />
```

Obeying `<meta>` refresh requests is a browser-side thing. Use DOM parsing to look for `<meta>` tags with the appropriate attributes in the response cURL gives you.

If you can guarantee that the response is valid XML, you could do something like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($cURLResponse);
$result = $xml->xpath("//meta[@http-equiv='refresh']");
// Process the $result element to get the relevant bit out of the content attribute
```