# Onload timeout preventing to use Curl

Tags: curl

I am trying to retrieve the content of a web page via cURL (let's say http://www.foo.com/bar.php).

When I load the website in the browser, an animation appears while the page is loading, and the page eventually shows up.

But with cURL, here is what is retrieved :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=http://www.foo.com/bar.php">
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            function waitLoad(){
                setTimeout("showWaitingAnimation()", 50);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="waitLoad()">
         Some stuff here
    </body>
</html>
```

And when I try to perform a curl to the refresh url, it returns exactly the same thing.

Any suggestion ?

Cheers,

A.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Can CURL follow meta redirects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820705/php-can-curl-follow-meta-redirects)

Comment: Well not really, because the page to which it's redirected to is exactly the same...

Comment: its really hard to know what that site is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Install the HttpFox Firefox Addon or a packet sniffer and inspect the requests and responses. Then try to emulate the same  headers and parameters with curl.