# Best tool to follow all redirects including meta-refresh / javascript redirects?

Tags: curl, redirect

Current implementation is in curl. Curl does not seem to be following all of the redirects and I am trying to determine the final page in a redirect sequence. Seeking new options.

Complete scan should be completed within 3-5 seconds.

The redirects are a mix of 302, 301, meta-refresh, and javascript redirecting. They are typically strung together, mixing different types with the sole purpose of stopping crawlers but allowing legitimate browsers to see the final site.

This is a common obfuscation technique in phishing emails. They may use a google search result redirection, then pointing to a Yandex redirection, to a  to the final destination.

I am not trying to scrape content, just to determine the hops in the redirect chain, and the final url so it can be submitted for evaluation.

We have already tried Curl and followed [PHP: Can CURL follow meta redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820705/php-can-curl-follow-meta-redirects) but the techniques vary for each type of document in the chain.

The results that I am attempting is to follow the following chains:

1. 301
2. 302
3. 303
4. 307
5. 308
6. Meta-Refresh
7. Javascript redirects https://love2dev.com/blog/ways-to-use-javascript-redirect-to-another-page/
8. Google results page redirect
9. Yandex redirects
10. Email provider tracking links redirects

We often see things like this

Email contacts a link:

Link type and how it redirects to the next hop.

1 -----> 6 -----> 9 ------> 7 ----> final destination

What I am trying to determine is the url of each of the steps, and then the final url as seen in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Until point 6 you'd be fine with curl. From point 7 specifically, you're in a real mess. The best method I see is to redevelop your code using a headless browser.

Google Chrome (amongst others) supports this:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

It will follow redirects naturally, and you can interact with it with Node-based tools.